# load data infile truncates data

Tags: mysql, linux, load-data-infile

I'm trying to import some user data into mysql.
The command I'm running is

```
load data infile "userdata.txt" 
into table userdata 
character set "ascii" 
fields terminated by ':';
```

The data is common password file:

email:password

The password part gets imported alright.
however the first column is weirdly truncated

| user_name | pass_word |
| --- | --- |
| _kazemi@ymail.com | xxxxxx |
| hkin@sehinc.com | xxxxxx |
| irmin@sbcglobal.net | xxxxxx |
| er015@yahoo.fr | xxxxxx |

you can see the emails in user_name are not right, The Data in the textile has no weird characters or so. The Emails are in the normal format xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx

Any ideas what I miss?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try adding a `LINES TERMINATED BY`

Comment: yes its CRLF - changing that destroys the result completely as expected

Comment: Why would that be _As Expected_

Comment: ah - I just meant that I was sure it was CRLF - so I did expect it to break if I change that.

Comment: How much of the emailaddress is being lost, can you show a few input lines and the resulting inserts on the table please

Comment: seems pretty random to me - not a fixed number of characters as it seems to me. I'm on the go right now will post later. thx so far

Comment: Provide file content which produces shown result.

Comment: you were totally right - it was that I had to provide the line terminator - I thought I did that earlier. But now double-checking your answer fixed it. Thanks a lot. Please post as an Answer so I can asccept

Comment: If you specify no FIELDS or LINES clause, the defaults are the same as if you had written this:


FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY '' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html